# Django-hosts wrong URLS.py

Tags: django, subdomain, django-urls

I am trying to configure something like this

user2.example.com -> load urls_user.py
www.example.com -> load urls.py

The issue I am facing now is everything is loaded through urls_user.py

I am using django-hosts from https://django-hosts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

```
settings.py


MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django_hosts.middleware.HostsRequestMiddleware' ,
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'user_shop.subdomainMiddleware.subdomainMiddleware',
    'django_hosts.middleware.HostsResponseMiddleware'
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'e_com.urls'
ROOT_HOSTCONF = 'e_com.hosts'
DEFAULT_HOST = "www"


hosts.py

from django.conf import settings
from django_hosts import patterns, host

host_patterns = patterns('',
    host(r'www', settings.ROOT_URLCONF, name='www'),
    host(r'127', settings.ROOT_URLCONF, name='127'),
    host(r'(?!www)\w+', 'e_com.urls_user', name='wildcard'),
)
```

Even if i remove everything to do with urls_user, it will still load that file.

I am working on localhost and use hexxie:8000 to run my subdomains.

------EDIT------

I have the django_hosts in my installed apps, thing is it worked for once until I turned off my server and restart it, from then the problem persists till now.

'user_shop.subdomainMiddleware.subdomainMiddleware' is just a script to get the subdomain

```
class subdomainMiddleware:

def process_request(self,request):
    domain_parts = request.get_host().split('.')
    subdomain = "www"
    if(len(domain_parts) > 2):
        subdomain = domain_parts[0].lower()

    request.subdomain = subdomain
```

And if I do a pip freeze this will show

```
  altgraph==0.10.2
bdist-mpkg==0.5.0
bonjour-py==0.3
Django==1.8.3
django-hosts==1.4
django-subdomains==2.0.4
macholib==1.5.1
matplotlib==1.3.1
modulegraph==0.10.4
mysql==0.0.1
MySQL-python==1.2.5
numpy==1.8.0rc1
Pillow==2.9.0
py2app==0.7.3
pyasn1==0.1.8
pycrypto==2.6.1
pyobjc-core==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Accounts==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-AddressBook==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptObjC==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Automator==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CFNetwork==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Cocoa==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Collaboration==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreData==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreLocation==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreText==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-DictionaryServices==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-EventKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ExceptionHandling==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-FSEvents==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-InputMethodKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-InstallerPlugins==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-InstantMessage==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-LatentSemanticMapping==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-LaunchServices==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Message==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-OpenDirectory==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-PreferencePanes==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-PubSub==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-QTKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Quartz==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ScreenSaver==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-SearchKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ServiceManagement==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Social==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-SyncServices==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-SystemConfiguration==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-WebKit==2.5.1
pyOpenSSL==0.13.1
pyparsing==2.0.1
python-dateutil==1.5
pytz==2013.7
scipy==0.13.0b1
six==1.4.1
Twisted==13.2.0
xattr==0.6.4
zope.interface==4.1.1
```

Comment: Here are a few quick thoughts before I try to reproduce this:
Is `'django_hosts'` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`?
What is `'user_shop.subdomainMiddleware.subdomainMiddleware'`? Could that be interfering somehow? Could you also include a `pip freeze`?

Comment: @Omni5cience Thanks for replying. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the error. It is an error in my urls.py file.